# How to implement "step-by-step" UI pattern in Android?

Tags: java, android, user-interface

I have a task to port some Iphone app to Android.  I've faced a problem. App should include step-by-step answering questions.  I wonder, how to implement this feature.  I thought about FragmentActivity, wich switches between predefined types of Fragments (I have static types of questions and answers, which are received from back-end).

Here is the iPhone screenshot:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Check out the [ViewFlipper](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ViewFlipper.html). It allows you to flip through several views. You could make one view for each question and then iterate through them

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend ViewPager with fragments. You can disable scrolling and select next page  on specific action.

[here is a tutorial from google](http://developer.android.com/training/animation/screen-slide.html)

Answer (score 0):

You could just implement a state diagram and inflate layouts according to your diagram if you have a finite count of state with static information.